# About to get an ActiveX control of MS Flex grid conrol in visual studio 2017 using VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, activex

since we have used MS flex grid control in Visual studio 6.0 using VC++, but we have upgraded to visual studio 2017.

when I try to open a dialog box in the source code in Visual C++ here is the message that I got:

message that I got:
( The ActiveX control "{6262D3A0-531B-11CF-91F6-C2863C385E30}" is not registered on this computer.
Register the control and try again.)

Comment: Have you checked this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/886ab070-ebb4-42a8-b791-16a349d493ba/msflexgrid?forum=vbgeneral?

Comment: On the same machine ? Are you sure it is registered with **RegSvr32** ?